# How do I find out my screen resolution from a shell script?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, xorg, resolution

How do I find out my screen resolution from a shell script?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+x[0-9]+).*$/\1/'
```

Command `xdpyinfo` displays various information about your X server. It writes a lot of things to the standard output but we only need the line starting with the word `dimensions`, thus we use `grep`. Finally we use `sed` to clean the result.

Comment: If you need x and y axis dimension separately, you can do the following. First, put the result of the above command into a variable using `$( )` syntax (i.e. `DIMENSIONS=$(xdpyinfo ...`). Then use `sed` again to get the two: `WIDTH=$(echo $DIMENSIONS | sed -r 's/x.*//')` and `HEIGHT=$(echo $DIMENSIONS | sed -r 's/.*x//')`.

Comment: `xdpyinfo` prints an error message if it cannot access information, so error redirection to `/dev/null`. For this reason you may want to add an error redirection: `xdpyinfo 2> /dev/null`. So, the full piple looks like this: `xdpyinfo 2> /dev/null | grep dimensions | sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+x[0-9]+).*$/\1/'`. This will make your script more solid.

Comment: `xdpyinfo | grep dimensions: | awk '{print $2}'` seems to be simpler and more readable.

Comment: I was looking for something simpler that did not use XWindows, and found this answer for my needs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263890/how-do-i-find-the-width-height-of-a-terminal-window

Answer (score 32):

`xdpyinfo | grep dimensions` will give you the total resolution, if you have multiple monitors it will be the sum of all of them. `xrandr --current` will give you the resolution for each monitor.

I use this snippet to find the maximum possible resolution for rDesktop without going to full screen:

```
Xaxis=$(xrandr --current | grep '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d 'x' -f1)

Yaxis=$(xrandr --current | grep '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d 'x' -f2)
```

Output:

```
Xaxis = 1280
Yaxis = 1024
```

Minus windows decoration (more or less):

```
MaxRes=$(($Xaxis-5))"x"$(($Yaxis-25))
```

Output:

```
MaxRes = 1275x999
```

Which is the max resolution for rDesktop without going full screen.

End command:

```
rdesktop -u $User -P -z -5 -g $MaxRes $Host &
```

It works fine so far but I haven't tested thoroughly though.

Another example is for screencast with `avconv`:

```
avconv -f x11grab -r 15 -s `xrandr --current | grep  '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}'` -i :0.0 -c:v libx264 ./output.mp4
```

Comment: it says> `xdpyinfo: Unable to open display "".`

Comment: How do you find out the available modes to change to?

Comment: If you don't need to subtract for window decoration (etc), you can do this in a one-liner `rdesktop [other_args] -g $(xrandr --current | grep '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}')`.

Comment: It's not the sum for multiple monitors. It's the dimensions of a bounding box which contains all the monitors.

Comment: `xrandr --current | grep '*' |  awk -v line="$SCREEN" 'NR==line{print $1}' | cut -d 'x' -f1` if you want to specify a screen (with a multi-monitor setup) (`SCREEN` is 1-indexed)

Answer (score 6):

A very simple method is to read out the `modes` file in the sys-directory:

```
cat /sys/class/graphics/*/modes
```

or respectively

```
cat /sys/class/graphics/*/virtual_size
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer for linux.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `xrandr -q` command. From that you can create a shell script if needed.

For more information on the command go [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2) or type ***man xrandr***

Answer (score 2):

```
#############################################
## I use this with a Video Recording Program.
#  window size --root option - information on the screen's root window
echo $(xwininfo -root | grep 'geometry' | awk '{print $2;}')
# output(s): 1024x768+0+0
#            height x width + x + y positions.
######################
## Reference Manual ##
man xwininfo
```

Comment: I used `xwininfo -root|sed '/Height/!d;s/.* //'` for height and `xwininfo -root|sed '/Width/!d;s/.* //'` for width.

Comment: geo=``xwininfo -root | grep 'geometry' | awk '{print $2;}'``
s=${geo%+0+0} ; This is how my BASH script is for 'avconv -s $s'

Answer (score 2):

## **Reading the Monitor Screen Data**

The vesa standard provides a method of how to read the monitor screen resolution.

> **Extended Display Identification Data (EDID**): This standard
>   defines data formats to carry configuration information, allowing
>   optimum use of displays.

A monitor typically supports multiple resolutions and refreshrates. Of course someone will prefer the maximum (physical) one.

To read this monitor data, try one of these solutions:

- **edid-decode**

  If not installed, type

  ```
  sudo apt install edid-decode
  ```

  Then read the `edid` file

  ```
  edid-decode /sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/edid
  ```
- **read-edid**

  Install with

  ```
  sudo apt install read-edid
  ```

  Then read via i2c the screen monitor data  and parse it

  ```
  sudo get-edid | parse-edid
  ```
- **Hexdump the edid data**

  In case edid-tools are not installed, you can dump the `edid` hex-file, e.g.:

  ```
  hd /sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/edid
  ```

  To encrypt this hex file  take a look at  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) or download the [edid specifications](http://read.pudn.com/downloads110/ebook/456020/E-EDID%20Standard.pdf).

Comment: If you dont have X and `xrandr` installed, `edid-decode` is a perfect tool when you want to know the supported resolutions of the connected monitor!

Answer (score 1):

`xdpyinfo` will do it, with some parsing.  It gives a lot of info which you'll then have to dig the screen number, and dimensions from

Answer (score 1):

Two possible alternatives produced combining the answers of @user31752 and @eliezer-e-vargas

A simpler regex:

```
$ xrandr --current | sed -n 's/.* connected \([0-9]*\)x\([0-9]*\)+.*/\1x\2/p'
1440x900
```

or using cut:

```
$ xrandr --current | grep ' connected ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d '+' -f 1
1440x900
```

The use of `grep '*' | uniq` from @eliezer-e-vargas get a different line (ex. " 1440x900 59.90*+ 59.89" ) of xrandr output, while the grep ' connected ' get a simple one (ex. "LVDS1 connected 1440x900+0+0 .....").

The use of regex by @user31752 is nice, so the line that I'm using needs a simpler regex, or can be substituted whit the simpler cut command.

Example xrandr output

```
$ xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1440x900      59.90*+  59.89  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Is there any reason for somebody to use these commands instead of the ones in [Eliezer E. Vargas’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/196532/150988#338697)?

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As in the accepted answer but less complicated:

```
xdpyinfo | grep dimensions
```

Example of output:

```
dimensions:    1366x768 pixels (361x203 millimeters)
```